# python pandas groupby about categorial variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Here is what my dataframe looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['01', 'aa', '1+', 1200],
        ['01', 'ab', '1+', 1500],
        ['01', 'jn', '1+', 1600],
        ['02', 'bb', '2',  2100],
        ['02', 'ji', '2',  785],
        ['03', 'oo', '2',  5234],
        ['04', 'hg', '5-', 1231],
        ['04', 'kf', '5-', 454],
        ['05', 'mn', '6',  45],
    ], columns=['faculty_id', 'sub_id', 'default_grade', 'sum'])

df
```

[image]

I want to groupby facility id, ignore subid, aggregate sum, and assign one default_grade to each facility id. How to do that? I know how to groupby facility id and aggregate sum, but I'm not sure about how to assign the default_grade to each facility.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what do you mean by "assign one default_grade"?  It looks as though you already have one `default_grade` assigned `per faculty_id`.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply different functions by column in a groupby using dictionary syntax.

```
df.groupby('faculty_id').agg({'default_grade': 'first', 'sum': 'sum'})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Bruce!